# How can i add linux bash script file into terraform code?

Tags: linux, bash, terraform

My requirement is I need to create 3 aws instances using terraform and run a 3 different bash scripts in it. All files are on same server.

I already have terraform code to create an infrastructure and 3 bash script ready to use.

```
resource "aws_instance" "master" {
  instance_type = "t2.xlarge"
  ami = "${data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id}"
  key_name = "${aws_key_pair.auth.id}"
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.public.id}"]
  subnet_id = "${aws_subnet.public1.id}"
}
```

this is my terraform code to create an AWS instance

But i am not sure how i can integrate both.

Also can i use Aws instance ip value as a variable value in linux bash script? If yes how can i pass that ip value to one of my linux bash script variable?
Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you include your code?

Comment: Local-exec in terraform but it did not work.

Comment: Are you using multiple accounts to edit the same post? Not the best idea, now your edit has to go through review.

Comment: You should read up on `count` in the context of terraform resources. This will allow you to create 3 similar instances. The IP can be used by referencing the instance resource during provisioning. All of this info is detailed here https://www.terraform.io/intro/getting-started/provision.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you only need to run your script once; then pairing with AWS' [user-data scripts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) is perfect for this.

Throw your script into the file `templates/user_data.tpl`, use the [template provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/template/index.html) to then create the template. And then you'll just want to pass the rendered script into the [user_data](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/instance.html#user_data) argument for your `aws_instance` resource.

Modify as necessary.

**templates/user_data.tpl**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ${master_ip}
```

**terraform_file.tf**

```
resource "aws_instance" "master" {
  instance_type          = "t2.xlarge"
  ami                    = "${data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id}"
  key_name               = "${aws_key_pair.auth.id}"
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.public.id}"]
  subnet_id              = "${aws_subnet.public1.id}"
}

resource "aws_instance" "slave" {
  instance_type          = "t2.xlarge"
  ami                    = "${data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id}"
  key_name               = "${aws_key_pair.auth.id}"
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.public.id}"]
  subnet_id              = "${aws_subnet.public1.id}"

  user_data = "${data.template_file.user_data.rendered}"
}

data "template_file" "user_data" {
  template = "${file("templates/user_data.tpl")}"

  vars {
    master_ip = "${aws_instance.master.private_ip}"
  }
}
```

Comment: That exactly what i was needed.. Thanks

Comment: For TF 0.12 you can also use this: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/templatefile.html